# Validate Against Values in a Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a method that checks if my `timeZoneId` is valid. This should be done by validating the `timezoneId` against the values in my database. I've been following an article by **Microsoft** (see link below), but having trouble extracting my `timeZoneId` from the current row in the database.

The article is using `txtEmail = datarow["Alias "].ToString();` to extract the data, but I'm dealing with an `int` value so this doesn't work. The error is occurring here: `timezoneId = datarow[0];` I've tried casting it to an `int`, but that doesn't seem to fix it. My error states

> Cannot convert source type 'object' to target type 'int'

**Question:** how can I properly extract the `timeZoneId` from the current row?

**Microsoft Link:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5z00s5e(v=vs.140).aspx

```
private void ValidateTimeZoneId(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DataView dv;
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    dv = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

    int timezoneId;

    args.IsValid = false;

    // Loop through table and compare each record against user's entry
    foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
    {
        // Extract timezoneid from the current row
        timezoneId = datarow[0];

        // Compare timezoneid against user's entry
        if (timezoneId == args.Value)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly cast this. It can be done two ways:

```
timezoneId = (int)datarow[0];
```

or

```
timezoneId = Convert.ToInt32(datarow[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this fixes the `timezoneId = (int)datarow[0];` line of code, my `if(timezoneId == args.Value)` fails because it Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'int' and 'string' is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: In that case change your if condition to be `if (datarow[0] == args.Value)
        {`

Comment: Cool, thanks again. Would it be improper to write it like `if(timezoneId == Convert.ToInt64(args.Value))` I'll mark this as the answer once stack allows me (6 minutes out)

Comment: You could do that, but a string comparison of the integer value is still fine.  Be sure to use ToInt32 though, not toInt64 for any conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You should better declare `timezoneId` as `string` then

```
string timezoneId;

    timezoneId = datarow[0] as string;

    // Compare timezoneid against user's entry
    args.IsValid = (timezoneId != null && timezoneId == args.Value);
```